# Kendo grid post data to MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am posting data to MVC controller like below but if the paging is enabled on the grid only data on one page is posted but not all the grid data.

*Code*

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.Occupation>()
    .Name("Occupations")
    .Columns(columns =>
     {
       columns.Bound(e => e.Name).ClientTemplate("#= Name #" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='Occupation[#= index(data)#].Name' value='#= Name #' />";
        columns.Bound(e => e.Industry).ClientTemplate("#= Industry #" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='Occupation[#= index(data)#].Industry' value='#= Industry#' />";
        })
    )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Occupations_Read", "People", new { Name = Model.Name}))
    )

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PersonPost(Models.Person p)
{
    //do stuff
}


 function index(dataItem) {

            var data = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
            return data.indexOf(dataItem);
        }
```

*Details*

I am posting data to MVC controller like above but if the pageing is enabled on the grid only data on one page is posted but not all the grid data.

Comment: When you use pagination, only the displayed records are render on the page. If your datasource has 1000 records, but your page shows only 10 record, there are only 10 inputs-hidden on the page. So, you can't post all the records to the controller using this technique

Comment: Then what is the best way to post the grid data along with other fields to controller

Comment: The question is to ambigous, there are multiple solutions, and I don't know the context, or what are you pretend to doing. You could simple store all the records in a session variable, or you can create all the hiddens manually, or you can render all the records without pagination, or.....